# Fogbugz Module for DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke, fogbugz, fogbugz-api

Is there a Fogbugz Module for DotNetNuke?

I googled it and couldn't find one.

Comment: What would you want this module to do? Reports? Time Entry?

Comment: @EfficionDave Reports mainly.  I want to be able to query a Fogbugz server via the Fogbugz-API and display a list of open issues (and project milestones) so that a client can view them in DotNetNuke.

Comment: @EfficionDave Actually it wouldn't hurt if they could file issues (bugs) as well.

Comment: I've written around 8 reports for FogBugz that I could easily turn into a DNN module. But they don't use the API, they go straight to the database. I've been contemplating the best way to share/sell them, but just don't really have the time to package them properly.

Comment: @EfficionDave I'm starting to write one now using the C# FogBugz API Wrapper, and of course DNN.

Comment: I'd be happy to beta test it for you :-)

Comment: @Dave I'm writing it for my employer, I'll see what they have to say about that when I'm done with it... :)

Comment: If it's okay with them I'll let you have at it!

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2011, there is no publicly available DNN Module for FogBugz.

For somebody who simply wants to submit bugs using the API, it would not be terribly difficult to make a DNN Module that accomplishes this.

I hope if @EfficionDave or @leannd00 finish a public version of their module that they will make it available on SnowCovered.

For now, I think the best bet is to make a request at the FogBugz stackexchange site.

It's Stackoverflow, but for FogBugz!

http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/